# Is having a Static Map like this a bad practice?

Tags: java, design-patterns, static, software-design

I want to have some important classes available through out the app, like so:

```
private static final HashMap<Class<?>, Object> _globals = new HashMap<>();

public MainClass(){
     _stateManager = new StateManager();
     _inputManager = new InputManager();
     _toolManager = new ToolManager();
     _viewManager = new ViewManager();
     _globals.put(StateManager.class, _stateManager);
     _globals.put(InputManager.class, _inputManager);
     _globals.put(ToolManager.class, _toolManager);
     _globals.put(ViewManager.class, _viewManager);
}
```

From what I've been researching, static vars are always discouraged, but I feel like this might be ok, because I'm not actually keeping any static state. The main purpose of _globals if to have it available for example in the class `TextFieldController` without having to pass it to the constructors, from the main class all the way to there, going through classes that might not need it.

Is this ok or is there any problems i'm not seeing ?

Comment: Just "a static map" isn't a bad practice, there is a lot of cases where this is useful and the gool solution.

Comment: I see a caveat in your example, as this is static, do not put the initialization into a public constructor.

Comment: Without knowing the rest of your code, to use  _globals (with values), you must instantiate an object of MainClass. Can be fine in your case. But in general, constructor are for constructing objects and their members, statics are bind to the class.

Comment: **Congratulations!** You have independently reinvented the little discussed [multiton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern). Personally, I think it has its uses. But be careful. One major disadvantage of global state is debugging and testing become more difficult.

Comment: This is clearly not a _multiton_: the Map holds only one instance per class. It is the [Service Locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) anti-pattern... not because the field is static, but because of all the dependencies throughout a codebase that it hides. Dependency Injection is the modern solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables, while not inherently problematic, can be classified as a code smell for a few significant reasons:

**Global State:** Static variables are essentially global state in disguise. Their state is preserved across the application's lifetime and can be accessed or mutated from any portion of the code, making it difficult to reason about behavior, leading to side effects and bugs.

**Concurrency Issues:** In multithreaded programming, static variables are shared among all threads. This can lead to race conditions and other synchronization problems unless handled carefully with locks, semaphores, etc.

**Coupling:** Static variables increase the coupling between components in your code. Changing the state of a static variable affects all the code that accesses it, making it harder to understand, maintain, and evolve the software.

**Testing:** Unit testing becomes more complicated when static variables are involved, as the shared state can persist between tests and cause tests to fail or pass unexpectedly. It can also make tests order-dependent.

**OOP Principles:** Static variables, particularly public ones, violate the principles of encapsulation and instantiation in Object-Oriented Programming (OOP). They contradict the idea of each object carrying its own state.

As for

> The main purpose of _globals if to have it available for example in the class TextFieldController without having to pass it to the constructors, from the main class all the way to there, going through classes that might not need it.

It seems like you're intending to replace the IoC (Inversion of Control) container and establish singletons through the use of static variables. This approach, however, is not generally recommended as a best practice. If you're not interested in using IoC frameworks, I recommend exploring the factory pattern as a lightweight option.

Comment: If I make sure the map is set on initialisation and remains the same always, it seems that all of the 5 points you made are solved, no?
factory pattern might still be a better solution, though

Comment: I still would advise against utilizing static variables for achieving your goals

Answer (score 0):

IMO it would be totally ok, if this constant will provide immutability, e.g.
I would use immutable map to avoid this constant modification after creation, for instance using Map.of() method since java 9.